# Use a trigger to sort a sheet every time a form is submitted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I'm trying to get a Google Sheet to automatically sort when a form is submitted. I have been able to set up the script to sort with the following, but it only works when the spreadsheet is edited manually (not when new data comes in from a form).

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 6;
  var tableRange = "A2:F100";

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){
  var tableRange = "A2:F100";

 if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){
 var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );
  }
}
```

I need to set up a trigger to make this go when a form is submitted. I found this on Google Developers, but I'm not sure what to use as ("myFunction") in the following:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
 .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
.onFormSubmit()
 .create();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form submission is not an edit, so onEdit trigger is useless here. Instead, use the following simple function with an installable trigger On Form Submission. It's easy to set a trigger manually: in the script editor, go to Resources > Current project's triggers, and add this:

[image: trigger]

The function:

```
function sortSheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var columnToSortBy = 6;
  var headers = 1;   // number of header rows, usually 1
  var range = sheet.getRange(headers + 1, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - headers, sheet.getLastColumn());
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );
}
```

Comment: This is better than what the OP was asking for. To do so literally, `myFunction` could be replaced with `onEdit` so a form submittal *does* mimic an `onEdit`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked, but now it is sorting the header row as well. How can I write it so that doesn't happen?